# Generating a token that I can prove I generated

Tags: security, encryption

I need to generate random tokens so that when I see them later I can determine absolutely that they were actually generated by me, i.e. it should be near impossible for anyone else to generate fake tokens. It's kind of like serial number generation except I don't need uniqueness. Actually, its a lot like a digital signature except I am the only one that needs to verify the "signature".

My solution is as follows:

1. have a secret string S (this is the only data not in the open)
2. for each token, generate a random string K
3. token = K + MD5(K + S)

to validate the token is one I generated:

1. split incoming token into K + H
2. calculate MD5(K + S), ensure equal to H

It seems to me that it should be impossible for anybody to reliably generate H, given K without S. Is this solution too simplistic?

Comment: how do you split the token to K + H? how do you know what's K?

Comment: he adds MD5 at the end of string, MD5 has a fixed length of 32 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you presented is on the right track. You're essentially performing [challenge-response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) with yourself. Each token can consist of a non-secret challenge string C, and HMAC(C, K) where K is your server's secret key.

To verify a token, simply recompute the HMAC with the supplied value of C and see if it matches the supplied HMAC value.

Also, as Vinko mentioned, you should not use MD5; SHA-256 is a good choice.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Comment: HMAC also intends to validate the message. But of course it's a safer approach at almost no extra cost.

Comment: Definitely a MAC application, since it's you proving it to yourself. Not sure they apply here, but replay attacks need careful consideration. The OP's on the right track, but use an accepted MAC algorithm rather than trying to reinvent one.

Answer (score 1):

That's not too simplistic, that's certainly a valid way to implement a simple digital signature.

Of course, you can't prove to anybody *else* that you generated the signature without revealing your secret key S, but for that purpose you would want to use a more sophisticated protocol like PKI.

Answer (score 1):

Just to nitpick a bit you would prove *only* that whomever has access to S could have generated the token. Another little detail: use a better hash, like SHA256. Because if Mallory is able to generate a collision, she doesn't even need to know S.